# WKWebView Cached Old S3 Bucket

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, wkwebview

I have an iOS app that gets a PDF from an S3 bucket
and displayed the PDF using WKWebView.

I have changed/updated the PDF when accessing the S3 link I see the new PDF
when using Android I see the new PDF

however iOS still shows the old PDF?  Any Ideas?

Is there a way to clear WebView Cache?
I have tried Settings clearing Safari cache
I have tried setting no-cache to the S3 bucket PDF

```
viewController.html = "https://xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/voucher/NEW.pdf"
let htmlData = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><header><meta name='viewport'></header><body><object width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" align='center' data='\(html)'></object></body></html>"
webview.loadHTMLString(htmlData, baseURL: nil)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[try to clean local web data](https://gist.github.com/insidegui/4a5de215a920885e0f36294d51263a15):

```
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
        records.forEach { record in
            WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
            print("[WebCacheCleaner] Record \(record) deleted")
        }
    }
```